# Does conditional normality imply normality?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, convergence

Suppose I have two random variable $X$ and $Y$, I know that for every $Y=y$, $X|Y=y \sim N(0,1)$. Can I get the conclusion that $X \sim N(0,1)$?

Another similar question is that suppose I have two sequence of random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$. if I know that for every $Y_n=y$, $X_n|Y_n=y$ converges in distribution to$ N(0,1)$. Can I get the conclusion that $X_n$ itself converges in distribution to $ N(0,1)$?

Comment: First question: $P(X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X \le x|Y = y) dF_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)dF_Y(y) =  \Phi(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dF_Y(y) = \Phi(x)$. So $X \sim N(0,1)$.  Agree?

Comment: Yes, for this one.

Comment: Does conditional normality of $X|Y=y$, and that fact does not actually depend on the value of $y$, imply normality? Um. Yes.Think about the question in plain English--you basically just said that $X$ is standard normal no matter what value $Y$ takes, and then asked if this means if that $X$ is standard normal regardless of $Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've quite written out your second question correctly.  The way it looks, you are conditioning on the sequence $Y_n = y\space \forall \space n$. An alternative *might* be:  for every sequence $\{Y_n\}$, the sequence $\{X_n|Y_n\}$ converges in distribution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**: $P(X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X \le x|Y = y) dF_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)dF_Y(y) =  \Phi(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dF_Y(y) = \Phi(x)$. So $X \sim N(0,1)$.

**Second question**:
$P(X_n \le x|Y=y) \rightarrow \Phi(x)$ for all $y$. Therefore, by dominated convergence (because the left-hand side is dominated by 1, which is integrable with respect to $dF_Y(y)$), we may take the integral of both sides with respect to $dF_Y(y)$, obtaining $\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X_n \le x|Y = y) dF_Y(y) \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)dF_Y(y)$, which evaluates to $P(X_n \le x) \rightarrow \Phi(x)$, thereby proving the assertion that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$.